# Epson Pervection v39 scanner and Debian Buster

Tags: debian, scanner

i can't get my scanner (epson pervection v39) to work under debian buster.

i downloaded the [drivers](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) from epson (the 64bit ones for my 64 bit system) and installed them without errors.

the scanner itself is recognized by os:
lsusb:
    Bus 002 Device 019: ID 04b8:013d Seiko Epson Corp.

sane-find-scanner:
    found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x013d [Epson Perfection V39]) at libusb:002:019

but scanimage -L:
    No scanners were identified.

xsane and image scan both state, there is no scanner

Any hints what I could do?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Am problems with the Epson V39 in debian buster. You will find that running `sane-find-scanner` with `sudo` will find it but I still can't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow,

the recent drivers version 1.3.28.x64 did not work, the obviously older iscan-gt-s650-bundle-1.0.0.x64 did.

bonus quest:

is there a possibility to assign one of the (hardware) buttons on the scanner to scan directly? (I only use it for documents, so the settings remain the same anyway)